# Inconsistent translation of dollar amounts

Tags: google-translate

Easy to replicate:  Either using API or Google translate from web browser, translate the following text from English to Spanish:

For plan year 2020: Your Flexible Spending Account balance is $800.00. Your Dependent Care Account balance is $200.00.

Currently returns:
Para el año del plan 2020: el saldo de su cuenta de gastos flexible es de $ 800,00. El saldo de su cuenta de cuidado de dependientes es $ 200.00.

That's right.  In the first amount, it translates the decimal point as a comma. In the second amount, it translates it as a decimal point.  In playing with this, it seems like depending on the words leading up to balance is, it chooses either the comma or decimal point.

Is there something I can set to force it one way or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behaviour you are presenting and noted the following insight:

- The format: $XXX.XX. will be translated as $XXX,XX. For example: $500.10. Will translate as $500,10. Also, $1050.100. Will be translated as $1050,00.

I have tried with other formats as $XXX,XX., $XXX,XXX. And they are translated with the same format. Also, since Google Translate and [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup) are based on machine learning algorithms, thus, the quality of the translation may vary according to different aspects.

Having said that, my recommendation for improving machine learning algorithms is by retrieving [feedback from Translation](http://translate.google.com) and use the pencil icon to suggest a better translation. Also, you could suggest feedback of Google Translation within the [Translate Community](https://translate.google.com/community).